# New Quote id generate on every time of getQuote() in magento

Tags: magento-1, quote, cart-items

When I try to get cart items by using `getQuote()` method like

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
```

It generates new quote id on every time of this line call. **`sales_flat_quote`** table growing rapidly and it will make a looping! And show the below error! Please check the screenshot!

> **Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '6000' reached, aborting!**

[image]

This issue occurs only some times and for some customers only. If I check in another system, Its showing fine! It rectify automatically after some times. But I can't understand why it happening.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have created custom module for add handling fee amount. I just wrote a code like get cart items quantity of specific category, and add fee amount based on this quantity. I have followed this [tutorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/). I'm just using Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote(); for get cart items.

```
 public function getitemqtys() { 
        $request = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $product->setId($item->getProductId());
            $cat_ids = $product->getResource()->getCategoryIds($product);       
            if (in_array(1057, $cat_ids)){
                $item_quanties+=$item->getQty();
            }
        }
        return  $item_quanties;
     }
```

Tried this code for get Cart item quantities of specific category!

Comment: This issue may raise due to any third module.you need to check that module

Comment: try `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();`

Comment: okay.. Thank you for your response. Let me check it.

Comment: @DRAJI : Have you get any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume the Gmi_Fee module is making bad things. Just a guess. Turn it off, monitor the logs whether it occurs again

Comment: I have created this module for add handling fee amount. I just wrote a code like get cart items quantity of specific category, and add fee amount based on this quantity. I have followed this [tutorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/).  I'm just using Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote(); for get cart items. I have updated that code in question. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Disabled XDebug and you will be fine.

This error message comes specifically from the XDebug extension. PHP itself does not have a function nesting limit. Change [the setting](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level) in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 10000
```

or in your PHP code:

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 10000);
```

As for if you really need to change it (i.e.: if there's a alternative solution to a recursive function), I can't tell without the code.

Comment: HI, Thank you for your response. In before, we have 2000 for **max_nesting_level** value. Due to this issue, we have increased that nesting level into 6000. I think, it only may not an issue. I have updated the question.

Comment: This solves only the problem if you DON'T have an endless loop.